# no matter whether = whether?

Tags: grammatical-person

Excuse me, does anyone know if the following two sentences are equal?

1. No matter whether it is a good book, I will not read it.
2. Whether it is a good book, I will not read it.

can we switch between "no matter whether" and "whether"?

thanks

Comment: I believe this question belongs to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This should not go to English Language and Usage without much improvement.

Comment: Also, English Language Learners is not the same thing as English Language and Usage. I believe that would require some revision to demonstrate research effort as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about grammar and correct usage of basic words, not about writing.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

1. **No matter** whether it is a good book, I will not read it.
2. Whether it is a good book **or not**, I will not read it.

Answer (score 1):

The second is probably grammatically correct, but it doesn't feel right to me somehow. I'm not sure why. I want an "or not" in there somewhere.

Comment: I think that the "or not" is technically needed in both sentences, but is more successfully implied in the first than in the second.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence does not feel to be grammatically correct.  The second sentence should be "Whether it is a good book **or not**, I will not read it".

It can be even made simple by writing "Even if it is a good book, I will not read it."